# CentOS Server Security

Tags: php, security, centos, fastcgi

I've been learning to setup servers to use for my web-apps - and have found that my favourite (fastest and easiest to get going) setup is CentOS5.5/Lighttpd/fastcgi and SQL. I don't, however, know how secure these are out of the box - I installed them using Yum and have modified some settings to encourage PHP to play ball - is there anything I should be doing to increase my security levels, prevent tampering with my scripts?

The server doesn't have FTP, any additional users from root, mail or anything else installed at all, and all directories are owned by lighttpd:lighttpd and not CHMOD for any world use. The greater world won't ever be using the apps I'm writing, they are for personal and for my employees / partners to keep track of money and clients (hence my wish for them to be secure).

Thanks guys!

Comment: Technically, this question could be proposed on http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would recommend serverfault though, seems to fit the best

Comment: There's just to much stuff to sensibly answer with a post here or on stackoverflow/security.stackexchange

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about servers (plural) and you have the budget / ability I would encourage you to only have servers that are client facing that serve static content only.  Move your PHP and SQL back to internal only.

1. Web server with 80 / 443 open to the world and the SSH port open only to trusted IP's or listening only on an internal interface you can access
2. Application server with port 80 listening only to requests from the front end web server through a private IP address (if possible).  Otherwise, restrict it's access to the public IP of the front end webservers and consider having HTTPS (443) communications between the two.
3. Your SQL instance / server should have the same concept, only being accessible from the Application server.

This allows you to have multiple levels of security and dedicated resources to process specific tasks (FE webserving / Middleware Application serving / Backend data services)

In addition, if your FE is compromised, they wont have **immediate** access to your PHP source and the database content.

If it is a single server, ensure only 80/443 are open to the world and make sure you have a firewall, or firewall concepts in place, to restrict/deny access to all other ports except from trusted sources.  Consider moving SSH from port 22 (default) to an alternate port ...

Comment: Very good points, I will just add, make sure you use passwords you will NEVER remember, put them in a password vault on a secure machine.  These passwords should be around 48 characters long (or use certificates).  That always just makes things more secure.

Comment: passwords?  come on now.  ssh keys!  take random chapters of a book as the keyphrase...

Comment: haha, a very good idea, I was thinking about the sql server specifically, but I always use 4096 keys for ssh.

Comment: Okay so I have a 64-char password that only my Mac knows, and only port 80 is open to the world (this server won't be serving SSL content) - IPtables is set to deny all other connections to the server, does that do the job firewall wise? I only have a single server at present but will definitely look at trying multiple server instances out - is there anywhere good to look for ideas on configuring such a rig? I was thinking using fcgi and passing it through the private IP address but my source is still then on the frontend machine. (Thanks!)

Comment: You can configure multiple virtual hosts on your single server.  One for "public" one for "private" -->  foo.example.com and foo.int.example.com ... you can set up foo.int.example.com in your /etc/hosts as it wont be served publicly and play with proxy_pass from external vhost to internal vhost